# Manually resort/split specific conversation

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-365

I sent an email to multiple addressees and received answers two three very separate topics that each developped into a discussion.

In outlook all emails are sorted as the same conversation due to the initial mail, however, I would like to split the conversation and future mails into the separate topics as one conversation each.

**Is there a way in MS outlook to split a conversation manually or to separate specific mails from a conversation?**

Note that I do *not* want to deactivate conversation sorting as whole, but just split up these specific (derailed) mail threads.

Comment: Try to edit the subject-line of the messages to separate as in [this link](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/edit-an-email-subject-line-08d60328-2a27-473e-8227-0b42a1ff2ce6). If this does not move the email to a new conversation, try to disable sorting by conversations and enable it again.

Answer (score 0):

There is no built-in feature in Outlook to split or merge conversations manually.
You can try the "Show as Conversations" feature in Outlook, which will merge all emails with the same subject into one conversation.
For different topics, if they have a different topic than the original topic, they will not be included in the current conversation.
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/view-email-messages-by-conversation-0eeec76c-f59b-4834-98e6-05cfdfa9fb07?ui=en-us&rs=en-us&ad=us

Comment: Just checking in to see if above information was helpful. If you have any further updates on this issue, please feel free to post back.